# How to change multiple checkbox action by object in React?

Tags: reactjs

I want to change the multiple checkbox action individually by react object value. How do I do this? I tried this way:

```
export default function changeNextPaymentDate() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [checked, setChecked] = useState({
    box1 : true,
    box2 : true
  });

  return (
    <Grid container spacing={2}>
      <Grid item xs={3}>
        <Box className={classes.paper} fontWeight='bold'> Change next payment date </Box>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={9}>
        <div style= {{ display:'flex'}}>
          <Checkbox
            checked = {checked.box1}
            onClick = {()=>{setChecked(!checked.box1)}}
          />          
          <Checkbox
            checked = {checked.box2}
            onClick = {()=>{setChecked(!checked.box1)}}
          />
          <Box className={classes.paper}>Change next payment date</Box>
        </div>        
        <Box className={classes.decStyle}>Change next payment functionallity descriptions  </Box>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Comment: Instead of `setChecked(!checked.box1)`, do `setChecked(state => ({...state, box1: !state.box1}))`. But this is not the most flexible way of doing it (check the answers and you'll probably find a more generic solution based on the component `name` attribute).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a function to handle the change of checked property of the input.

```
const handleChange = useCallback((event) => {
     setChecked(prev => ({...prev, [event.target.id]: event.target.checked}))
}, []);
```

Add `id` and `onChange` prop to the checkbox

```
<Checkbox
     checked = {checked.box2}
     id="box2"
     onChange = {handleChange}
 />
```

Then your code will look like below

```
export default function changeNextPaymentDate() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [checked, setChecked] = useState({
    box1 : true,
    box2 : true
  });
  const handleChange = useCallback((event) => {
      setChecked(prev => ({...prev, [event.target.id]: event.target.checked}))
  }, []);

  return (
    <Grid container spacing={2}>
      <Grid item xs={3}>
        <Box className={classes.paper} fontWeight='bold'> Change next payment date </Box>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={9}>
        <div style= {{ display:'flex'}}>
          <Checkbox
            checked = {checked.box1}
            id="box1"
            onChange = {handleChange}
          />          
          <Checkbox
            checked = {checked.box2}
            id="box2"
            onChange = {handleChange}
          />
          <Box className={classes.paper}>Change next payment date</Box>
        </div>        
        <Box className={classes.decStyle}>Change next payment functionallity descriptions  </Box>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set new state value, which is based on value of the state, you have to use the setState callback, which is passed with previous state value.
In your case:

`onClick = {() => setChecked(prevState => {...prevState, box1: !prevState.box1})}`

`...prevState` spreads all other box states. For further experience, you have to always mutate the prevState value. If you don't, the Component will not rerender.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have maintained checkboxes state in a object, you may want to spread the object and then update the corresponding checkbox by getting its `name` or `id` from the event.

Try the following code. This uses native HTML checkboxes. The approach should be similar

Link to the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-forked-y9jbl?file=/src/index.js:0-764

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const CheckboxExample = () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState({
    box1: false,
    box2: false
  });
  console.log(checked);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setChecked((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.checked
    }));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        name="box1"
        type="checkbox"
        checked={checked.box1}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        name="box2"
        checked={checked.box2}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<CheckboxExample />, rootElement);
```